# FitBark Oauth Authorization Code Redirect Stuck In Loop

Tags: android, redirect, oauth-2.0, authorization

New to android, practicing 3-legged Oauth with [FitBark API](https://www.fitbark.com/dev/).  I have it working outside of Android Studio.

1. First Leg, Chrome browser, successfully getting to User Allow Access to App screen and getting authorization code.
2. Second Leg, POSTMAN using Authorization code, successfully getting access token.
3. Third Leg, using curl in terminal with access token, successfully returning JSON with user profile information for the Get User Info API endpoint.

**Does not work in Android Studio:**

I'm stuck on the First Leg in Android Studio.  I'm using the [Retrofit Oauth tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/oauth-2-on-android-with-retrofit).

I can initiate the First Leg, App opens the FitBark login screen in Browser, and I can log in as a user.

[image]

Once that is a complete, the browser redirects to another page and displays the Authorization code.

[image]

But, I don't want it to open the browser and display the auth code.  I want it to redirect back to App after Login/Allow Access.  Once it redirects backs to my app, my understanding is I can capture the response(which I'm assuming is the auth code) in the Intent and get at it with .getData().

The retrofit guide and various sources on stack and other places all point to adding specific code to the Android Manifest, In the Intent Filter, Under the Activity that I initiate the First Leg call in.

The FitBark redirect_uri that came with my credentials:

`urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` is set to a constant of FITBARK_REDIRECT

In my Login Activity (in onCreate) for testing to get Authorization code:

```
public void getAuthCode(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(ServiceGenerator.FITBARK_BASE_URL + "/authorize?response_type=code&client_credentials&" + "client_id=" +FITBARK_CLIENT_ID + "&redirect_uri=" + FITBARK_REDIRECT));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

My onResume in the Login Activity, that is supposed to get the data from the Intent. This code does fire but I'm getting null from `getIntent.getData()`.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        // the intent filter defined in AndroidManifest will handle the return from ACTION_VIEW intent
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri == null){
            Log.d("On RESUME", "Gets Here");

        }
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(intentRedirect)) {
            // use the parameter your API exposes for the code (mostly it's "code")
            String code = uri.getQueryParameter("code");
            Log.d("CODE", code);
            if (code != null) {
                // get access token
                // we'll do that in a minute
            } else if (uri.getQueryParameter("error") != null) {
                Log.d("ERROR URI", "ERROR ERROR ERROR");
            }
        }
    }
```

**My android manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.macbook.retrofit">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="app.open"
                android:scheme="myapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

From reading guides, my understanding  is `android:host` and `android:scheme` needs to match up with my redirect_uri in the FitBark first leg call. So I've tried that by add myapp://app.open" to the call.

```
Uri.parse(ServiceGenerator.FITBARK_BASE_URL + "/authorize?response_type=code&client_credentials&" + "client_id=" +FITBARK_CLIENT_ID + "&redirect_uri=" + "myapp://app.open"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Before adding "myapp://app.open", I set it as a custom redirect through FitBark's API through the terminal.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer <My Token Value goes Here>" -H 
"Content-Type: application/json" -d 
'{"redirect_uri":"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob\rmyapp://app.open"}' 
"https://app.fitbark.com/api/v2/redirect_urls"
```

**The loop:**

When I click the button (on Main) to start the Login Activity, the getAuthCode() fires in the onCreate of Login.  The browser opens and then it gets stuck in a loop.

So, that's where I am at.  I want to get the Authorization Code and use it in the Second Leg but I'm unable to figure it out.   Please help!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks for rubber ducking this with me :)

I have my `getAuthCode()`  in my onCreate for the Activity...

Activity calls getAuth
getAuth redirects back to Activity...which onCreates again...

duh.